# C++ Program to Remove given Character from the sentence doesn't work

Tags: c++, char

The program just remove characters from the first word and not from all sentence.
How can I fix it? I need remove all characters from the sentence and not only the first world. 
Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    char c;

    std::cout << "Enter the string : ";
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << "\nEnter the character : ";
    std::cin >> c;
    /* Removing character c from s */
    s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), c), s.end());
    std::cout << "\nString after removing the character "
              << c << " : " << s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't read the whole sentence. You can use [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::cout << "Enter the string : ";
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/QCHJz4)